# Integer variable declaration in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in Ruby, i am trying to declare a simple variable in ruby which can store `int` type value.

I have tried the following codes

```
var=5
puts var
```

and

```
@var=5
puts @var
```

The output in both program is `5` , can anybody explain what is the difference in both type of code.

Comment: RTFM, for example this one: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/ciscoleal/ruby-vars-intro

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_variables.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are talking about type of variables in ruby language.

```
var = 5 is local variable
```

and

```
@var  = 5 is instance variable
```

The main difference between local and instance variable is that local variable is only available in controller, where as instance variable is available in corresponding views also. The controller and views do not share local variables.

For more details have look to below links:

[Ruby Programming/Syntax/Variables and Constants](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants)

[Variables in Ruby](http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/variables/)

Answer (score 1):

var is a local variable and @var is an instance variable

The main differences between local and instance variables are as follows

1. local variable has its scope restriction i.e not available to another methods where as instance available to another
2. local and instance variable is also available in view
3. instance variable is separate for each object

Answer (score 0):

@var is an instance variable, usually it is used in classes.

Answer (score 0):

`var = 5` is local varibale and this is only accessible from within the block of its.

`@var = 5` is instance varibale and  an instance variable belongs to the object itself.